# Handling json object with special characters in jq

Tags: bash, sh, jq

I have a json object with below element,

```
rsrecords="{


 "ResourceRecords": [
        {
            "Value": "\"heritage=external-dns,external-dns/owner=us-east-1:sandbox,external-dns/resource=service/api""
        }
    ], 
    "Type": "TXT", 
    "Name": "\\052.apiconsumer.alpha.sandbox.test.net.", 
    "TTL": 300
}"
```

And in my bash script,I have below code snippet,

```
jq  -r '.[] | .Name ,.ResourceRecords[0].Value' <<< "$rsrecords" | \
while read -r name; read -r value; do
  echo $name
```

Output is printed as,
 \052.apiconsumer.alpha.sandbox.test.net.

But I am expecting it to print as `\\052.apiconsumer.alpha.sandbox.test.net.`, which is , as it is "Name" from the json object..

How can this be done?

Comment: `echo "$name"`?

Comment: Make sure that your example is reproducible. In the current form it will produce a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before getting to the heart of the matter, please note that

1. the sample data as given is a bit of a mishmash, so I'll assume you meant something like:

```
rsrecords='
{
  "ResourceRecords": [
    {
      "Value": "heritage=external-dns,external-dns/owner=us-east-1:sandbox,external-dns/resource=service/api"
    }
  ],
  "Type": "TXT",
  "Name": "\\052.apiconsumer.alpha.sandbox.test.net.",
  "TTL": 300
}
'
```

2. Your jq query does not match the above JSON, so I'll assume you intended the query to be simply:

```
.Name, .ResourceRecords[0].Value
```

In any case, with the above JSON, the bash commands:

```
jq  -r '.Name, .ResourceRecords[0].Value' <<< "$rsrecords" |
while read -r name; read -r value; do
    echo "$name"
done
```

yields:

```
\052.apiconsumer.alpha.sandbox.test.net.
```

This is correct, because the JSON string `"\\X"` is an encoding of the raw string: `\X`

If you want to see the JSON string, then invoke jq without the -r option.  If you want to invoke jq with the -r option and want to see two backslashes, you will have to encode them as four backslashes in your JSON.